# In PostScript: How to place some stack elements (computed at run-time) into a procedure that can be assigned to a name?

Tags: postscript

Example with values 10 and 20 known **before run-time** to give better understanding of the  actual question below:

`/point1 { 10 20 } def` places the numbers 10 and 20 into a (anonymous) procedure
and then assigns it to the name `point1` (so it isn't anonymous any more).
Then name `point` can be used, i.e. whenever the interpreter finds it, it
will execute `{ 10 20 }`, i.e. 10 and 20 will be pushed onto the stack.

Stack before and after executing `def`:

```
Stacke before:             Stack after:
{ 10 20 }                  -
/point1

Dict before:               Dict after:
-                          point1 --> { 10 20 }
```

Now the actual question: Suppose the two values 10 and 20 will be computed **at run-time**. How to assign them (or any number of top `n` stack elements)
to a given name in order to use it later?

```
Stacke before:             Stack after:
<y>                        -
<x>
/<name>

Dict before:               Dict after:
-                          <name> --> { <x> <y> }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In postscript, procedures are just arrays with the *executable flag* set. So you can construct an array (however you like) and then call `cvx` on it.

```
/x 3 def
/y 4 def
[ x y ] cvx  % { 3 4 }
x y [ 3 1 roll ] cvx
x y 2 array astore cvx
{ //x //y }
({//x //y}) cvx exec
({//x //y}) token pop exch pop
```

So, for your hypothetical procedure, it could be done like this:

```
/makepairproc { % x y  ->  { x y }
    [ 3 1 roll ] cvx
} def
```

Another interesting thing you can do is have an executable array and a literal array of *the same underlying array* at the same time. You could use one defined as the *procedure* name and the other defined as a target. This way you can update the contents without allocating new memory every time.

```
/point1 { 10 20 } def
/point1arr //point1 cvlit def

30 40 point1arr astore  %update contents
point1  % 30 40         %execute contents
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I wanted. I didn't know the `cvx`command.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, why not just execute the script that produces the values? Then they are on the stack just as after calling "point1".

But you can use

```
/xyz [ <call you procedure producing the numbers> ] cvx def
```

so xyz contains a procedure producing the two produced numbers on the stack...

Comment: Why not executing the script that produces the values? Because I want to use the values many times, so I don't want them to be calculated over and over again.

Comment: @Curd Stefan means that in general you can wrap `[` ... `]` around any code to capture the results as an array. This could be in an `/init` procedure or in the top-level code, so he's not suggesting to execute it multiple times. It's a generalization of the first (code) line of my first example where `x y` is the `<call your procedure(s) producing the numbers>`.

Comment: @luserdroog, I originally did mean to execute it every time indeed, but had in mind that there could be reasons (like it being "expensive" or depending on a special context) not to do it