# Executing a string as PostScript instructions

Tags: postscript

I have programmatically constructed a string, for example

```
(/r1 [256 782 502] def)
```

I'd then like to execute the string as PostScript instructions in order to have the array on the stack.

How can I execute a string object?

Comment: You can simply apply the 'cvx' operator to your string to turn it into an executable object, then use the 'exec' operator to execute it. You don't need the initial \r but it won't cause any problems since that's a white space token in PostScript

Comment: `\r1` is probably meant to be `/r1` to make a literal name `r1`.

Comment: Thats correct, I meant /r1.

Comment: @KenS. I tryed your suggestion. It works til the cvx, but flashes error with the exec.

Comment: OK @KenS. It worked. Was anpother misstyping of mine :-) tks!

Comment: Good, glad to hear it worked :-)

Comment: @Isidro Gil: Why not fix the incorrect example in the question? ("edit")

Answer (score 1):

As commented by Ken, you can call `cvx` on a string to make it executable, and then call `exec` on it.

That will execute the contents of the string as PostScript source.

Comment: I have a similar question: When constructing two paths in parallel, I'd like to save the instructions for the second path until the first path has been drawn (with different attributes). How can I postpone or save generic instructions to execute them later?

Comment: See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38002304/in-postscript-how-to-place-some-stack-elements-computed-at-run-time-into-a-pr/38007943?r=SearchResults&s=7|26.2300#38007943)

Comment: If I want to put (e.g.) `3 1 roll` in the array, how would I prevent any operation to be executed before `cvx`? Writing `3 1 /roll` instead?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking. I think maybe you should start a new question.

Comment: OK, I will ask for a solution!